# Redirect all traffic to www subdomain (http to http) and (https to https) with Namecheap

Tags: http, redirect, https, dns, namecheap

I am hosting my own server using a domain I bought on Namecheap. Therefore I created an A record that points from `www` to my public IP address. My server redirects all requests to HTTPS already, hence I figured I do not need to set up an HTTP to HTTPS redirect anymore. The current setup is like follows:

[image]

Calling `http://example.com` now successfully redirects to `https://www.example.com`.

Calling `https://example.com` hangs forever.

**How do I redirect from `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`?**

Comment: This is closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266066/redirect-https-example-com-to-https-www-example-com-namecheap-and-heroku. The only solution posted there involves adding a CNAME record for @ which is generally not recommended (https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/579/2237/which-record-type-option-should-i-choose-for-the-information-im-about-to-enter).

Comment: Also closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581172/namecheap-domain-wont-redirect-without-www?rq=1